# Search a string for certain numbers

Tags: c#, regex, search

I'm trying to come up with a lightning fast solution to find portions in a string. Here is a Sample string:

"PostLoad successful! You transferred amount of **17.00** Rs to **03334224222**. Now use PostLoad by dialing 123. PostLoad on SMS will end on 01-03-2011."

Objective: Need to retrieve the bold values: Amount and Cell Number. The string contents change slightly but the cell number will always be a 11 digit. The amount is always with two decimal precision. Any suggestions using C# and RegEx?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(\b\d+\.\d{2}\b).*?(\b\d{11}\b)");
Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResults.Success) {
    for (int i = 1; i < matchResults.Groups.Count; i++) {
        Group groupObj = matchResults.Groups[i];
        if (groupObj.Success) {
            // matched text: groupObj.Value
            // match start: groupObj.Index
            // match length: groupObj.Length
        } 
    }
```

**Explanation:**

```
(       # Match and capture the following:
 \b     # Assert that the match starts at a "word boundary"
 \d+    # Match one or more digits
 \.     # Match a .
 \d{2}  # Match exactly two digits
 \b     # Assert that the number ends here
)       # End of first capturing group
.*?     # Match any number of intervening characters; as few as possible
(       # Match and capture...
 \b     # Word boundary
 \d{11} # Exactly 11 digits
 \b     # Word boundary
)       # End of match
```

Group #1 will contain the decimal number, group #2 will contain the 11-digit number.

A "word boundary" is the position *between* an alphanumeric character and a non-alphanumeric character, so it only matches at the start or end of a "word or number".

This ensures that numbers like `12.3456` will not be matched; on the other hand, it is necessary for the numbers to be delimited by whitespace, punctuation or other non-alnum characters. For example, in `number12.34` the regex would not match `12.34`.

Comment: +1, Good explanation. Why would `.*?` be *as few as possible* ?

Comment: @KMan: Usually, quantifiers like `*`, `?`, `+` or `{n,m}` always try to match as many characters as they can, and only relinquish those when needed for the overall match to succeed. When followed by a `?`, they try to match as few as possible, only adding more characters when needed for the overall match. If in this case the `?` was dropped, and the string contained two pairs of matching numbers, the `.*` would match all the way from the first number of the first pair to the second number of the second pair.

Comment: @KMan: Perhaps I should mention the technical terms, too: Usually, the quantifiers are *greedy*, and by postfixing them with a `?`, they become *lazy* or *reluctant*. So `.?` matches one character if it can, but will be content with not matching it if necessary. `.??` will not match anything until forced to do so, in which case it will match one character. See also [this regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: +1 for writing a detailed explanation instead of just providing a working regex.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed walk-through.

Comment: I noticed that for string like: "Rs.55.58.PostLoad successful!", "Balance transferred : 55.58 Rs. PostLoad successful!", or "Rs.55.58. PostLoad successful!", the RegEx doesn't match any group. Is some modification required?

Comment: Well, the second (11-digit) number is missing, therefore the regex fails. It's not trivial to make that second number optional without restructuring the regex. The easiest thing would be to make a regex that can match either type of number and then iterate through all the results. Then the entire match will contain either type of number, and you'd have to find out which in a second step. Regex: `\b(?:\d+\.\d{2}|\d{11})\b`

Comment: You are correct about the second condition of 11 digits missing. I'd rather have a separate RegEx for the smaller strings with amounts only. So \b(?:\d+\.\d{2})\b should work? I'll have to get back home to try it out.

Comment: Yes, it should work, but if there is no alternation you don't need grouping, so `\b\d+\.\d{2}\b` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conversion to VB.Net. I hope I got it right.

```
Dim regexObj As New Regex("(\b\d+\.\d{2}\b).*?(\b\d{11}\b)")
Dim matchResults As Match = regexObj.Match(lActualSenderMessage)

While matchResults.Success
    For i As Integer = 1 To matchResults.Groups.Count - 1
        Dim groupObj As Group = matchResults.Groups(i)
        ' matched text: groupObj.Value
        ' match start: groupObj.Index
        ' match length: groupObj.Length
        If groupObj.Success Then
        End If
    Next
End While
```